# Are women allowed to let their hair loose? Why are Goddesses depicted with their hair untied?

Tags: tradition, women, goddess, scripture, smriti

Pictures commonly found across the internet depict Goddesses with their hair untied. Example:

[image]

My knowledge is that women shouldn't have their hair untied. I've also heard in discourses (*pravachanams*) that a woman should never let her husband see her with untied hair.

With that in mind, I had these questions:

- What do our śāstras say in this regard? Can a woman leave her hair loose or untied?
- Is depicting Goddesses with their hair untied, against what our śāstras recommend?
- Another observation I've made is that North Indians are quite okay with Goddesses with untied hair, whether it's a painted picture or a digital image; however, South Indians condemn that practice. To what extent is my observation correct?

I tried searching for these doubts on the internet, but the best I got was a forum filled with opinions of few ladies who believe it's harmless to discontinue traditional practices that are not "modern".

Comment: It is not uncommon to see several (traditional and also strict tantrik) representations of Devi with untied hair. See Kali or Tara for example, named Muktakeshi (with flowing hair) which represents in tantrik symbolism such power of Shakti in action. The interpretation depends on different cults. But it is not wrong to represent Devi with such untied hair, see the large cult of Kali, which, indeed, has her hair untied, flowing free. That is one point of view regarding Devi. If you refer to local beliefs you will find every city and place having different views.

Comment: How knowing answers to questions such as this will benefit a devotee or a spiritual aspirant is beyond my limited comprehension..

Comment: Related [Why is it that women are advised to tie their hair when they visit temples?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11577/3500)

Comment: @Rickross, the question has 2 parts - one is about shastras regd. why women should not leave their hair loose. Following shastras helps one climb the spritual ladder, so it is benefitial

Comment: In general, devi does not have her hair untied. All soumya forms of devi are described as having flowers in their tied locks (e.g. campakAzOka punnAga sougandhika lasat kaca in Lalita 1000). Loose untied hair is seen in the ugra  or battle-driven forms of devi. Loose hair in soumya forms is likely an artist's interpretation of devi's adjectives such as vyOmakEzi

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO:
first i would first appreciate the scence of enquiry ,
 but we observe in all pauranic stories that all rishi patnees are depicted with long hair and even various forms of goddess all have again long hair.
 it is believed that it signifies "Ksheel" (sorry not word in english to make you understand better) of a lady.
 moreover i even asked an ayurveda doctor who is a good friend of mine she also agreed that ladies shouldn't cut their hair  because of it's deep connection with harmones.

but weather to tie or not it depends situation to situation ,
there is no serious issue or concept regarding this ..

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite Authentic sources such as Puranas.