# Why are women advised to tie their hair in temples?

Tags: belief, temple, culture, women

Once when I visited a Durga temple, a man who was giving out flowers to all devotees told me to tie my hair and not leave it open in the temple. I genuinely want to know the reason.

Comment: I can't site any  śastra but I can say from what I've heard from elders. So it might not be fully right. Lose hair is associated with amaṅgala(inauspiciousness). Usually during death in household, women let their hair lose. This is a cultural norm & can differ from region to region.

Comment: Loose, open hair is an invitation to ghosts and other energy-stealing negative elements.

Answer (score 13):

Setting your hair loose is not suggested not only when you visit temples but also when you are at home. Setting your hair loose is an indication of sorrow, grief, inauspicious things poverty and sins.

- Draupadi devi in Mahabharata does not tie her hair after her insult from the Kauravas in the kurusabha. She vows that she would only tie a knot to her hair when washed with the blood of Dushhasana. She was in immense anger and grief and she set her hair loose.
- Loose hair is an invitation to [Jyeshta devi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jyestha_%28goddess%29), the goddess associated with poverty, sorrow, inauspicious things and bad fortune. Tied hair (plaited) is an invitation to Lakshmi devi, goddess of wealth, fortune, prosperity. Ladies who cook food and brush their teeth with loose hair are vulnerable to Jyeshta Devi.
- Especially, elders advise to plait the hair rather than putting a clip because the bottom part of the hair of a woman has the abiliy to awaken the power of [**Kundalini Shakthi**](http://kundalinicare.com/?page_id=77). So it is advised to be with plaited hair than loose hair.
- When you consider general reason for it, loose hair is more likely to hair fall and hair is not supposed to fall in our homes. So it should be prevented by tying it.

  Hence loose hair is strictly forbidden in temples which are places of happiness and prosperity and places of God. For the reasons stated above, it is also forbidden anytime in Hindu religion.
  A similar question is answered by Dr.Machiraju Venugopal in an episode of TV show called Dharmasandehalu. Watch it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iz3FF4bAmT8).

Comment: It would be more useful if you cite some source (scriptures rather than youtube) or quotes/sayings of guru regarding these points.

Comment: @Pandya Do you see that I answered it based on video from a scholar named Dr.Machiraju Venugopal? Plus cite some source is not a correct way. You should say which sentence. Do you remember the meta post which you answered yourselves?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes, I said for "points you have written" e.g for "Setting your hair loose is an indication of sorrow, grief, inauspicious things poverty and sins." And consider second point Jyeshta Devi, Laxmi Devi...

Comment: @Pandya You did not mention which points I should add sources in the answer earlier & say it now when I ask. "Some" is never clear. The orator speaks of those points also. He mentions open hair is an invitation of evil forces causing misery etc.,. Daridra Devata is none other than Jyeshta Devi who gives misery etc. Suppose a video says Lakshmi's wife and I write Lakshmi here while translating or paraphrasing, I don't think that needs a banner for Lakshmi is Vishnu's wife. Does it? Orator speaks that ancient people didn't follow this custom and were prosperous.These are not really my words